# Laravel intervention image adding text with font is showing error

Tags: image, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Intervention package in Laravel5 for Inserting a text in image, and its is working well. But if I add font(.ttf) it shows the following error. The directory is correct.

> **NotSupportedException in Font.php line 30: Internal GD font () not available. Use only 1-5.**

```
        $image = Image::make(public_path('/userimage/') . "user.png");
        $image->text('text string', 10, 5, function($font) {
            $font->file(asset('/web/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'));
            $font->size(50);
            $font->color('#fdf6e3');
            $font->angle(45);
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

1. The GD library does not support custom fonts. You are supposed to use Imagick. Go to config/image.php and edit the **driver** value to **'imagick'** (after you actually install the extension for it):

   'driver' => 'imagick'
2. `asset('/web/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf')` returns an **URL**. You have to provide a path. Use `public_path('web/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf')` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Use `base_path()` instead of `asset()`.

Example:

```
$font->file(base_path('public/web/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:    $font->file(public_path('fontnameExample.ttf'));

Comment: It worked locally but not on shared hosting. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

- Try removing leading slash in path.
- Run `dd(asset('/web/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'))` and see if it matches
  expected path.

Answer (score 1):

Two things you can try:

- Remove the forward slash in the path to font file: `$font->file(asset('web/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'));`
- Make sure the font file is readable by Laravel / Apache, run `chmod 755 path/to/web/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf` just in case.

Answer (score 1):

```
Removing public_path() worked for me. 

   

     $image = Image::make('userimage/') . "user.png";
                $image->text('text string', 10, 5, function($font) {
                    $font->file('web/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf');
                    $font->size(50);
                    $font->color('#fdf6e3');
                    $font->angle(45);
                });
```